# Input system in unity worked before restart

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, 2d

I'm currently trying to make a game. My interactable object, which worked hours ago stopped working after I closed and now opened Unity. I tried restarting Unity, restarting my pc, making new control scheme. It just doesnt trigger on this object. Everything else works as it should, player moves, but this just doesnt work. here is the code for interactible object:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
NewInputActions inputActions; //b
private float interInput; //b

public class SelectableObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public OutlineMaker outl;
    private bool isOutActive;

    private void Awake()
    {
        inputActions.Other.Interact.started += ctx => interInput = ctx.ReadValue<float>(); //b
        inputActions.Other.Interact.performed += ctx => interInput = ctx.ReadValue<float>(); //b
        inputActions.Other.Interact.canceled += ctx => interInput = ctx.ReadValue<float>(); //b
    }

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Debug.Log(interInput);
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(player.gameObject.transform.position, this.gameObject.transform.position);
        if (dist < 5 && !isOutActive)
        {
            outl.EnableOutline();
            isOutActive = true;
        } else if (dist > 5 && isOutActive) 
        {
            outl.DisableOutline();
            isOutActive = false;
        }
    }
    public void OnInteract()
    {
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(player.gameObject.transform.position, this.gameObject.transform.position);
        Debug.Log(dist > 5);
        Debug.LogWarning("DETECTED E");
        if (dist > 5)
        {
            this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

The OnInteract method just doesnt get called.
[The control scheme in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQmj5.png)
[The setting on the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVsof.png)

(Just repeating from description)I tried restarting Unity, restarting my pc, making new control scheme. It just doesnt trigger on this object.

Update: There were some parts commented out(tagged with //b after), but with them the script gets disabled on start and still doesnt work with them enabled

Comment: The event needs to be registered using "+="

Comment: you seem to have commented out the bits you need

Comment: Is the **Active Input Handling** in Project Settings set to **New Input System**?

Comment: @Obscure021 It wasnt, now it is and still nothing

Comment: Restart the editor, I usually set Input Handling for both to allow using the old Input System for debugging.

Comment: @Obscure021
 Done that, even restarted the PC. The only thing that really changed is the verison of unity hub ,but I dont think that should matter

Comment: Are you sure you havent removed the input package? Or set the player settings to old?

Comment: Yea, the movement for player works, so...

Comment: I dont recgnise the playerinput choices, but "send messages"? what other choices are there?

Comment: @BugFinder https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Components.html#notification-behaviors

Comment: Ive never put the player input onto a game object, just made and used.. never had a burning need but as suspected you arent raising events.. so you need to change it.. back to you